# How to design a DB for several projects

Tags: database

Im wondering what will be the best way to organize my DB. Let me explain:

Im starting a new "big" project. This big project will be composed by few litle ones. In general the litle projects are not related to each other, they are just features of the big one.

One thing that all the projects have in common is the users that are going to use it.

So my questions are:

- Should i create different DB for each one of the litle projects
  (currently each project will contain 4-5 tables)
- How to deal with the users? Should I create one DB for all the users
  or should i
     duplicate the users table in every DB? Have in mind that the
     information about the users is used a lot in every litle project,
     it's NOT only for identification purposes.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: How much duplicate data will be shared amongst the projects for the users?

Comment: A lot, users table (~ 1000 records), contains information like names, contacts, location, departments, access level (~20 columns), and all the small projects are using information from user's table at least once on every page, which means that i will need to switch the DBs like hell if i chose to make a separate DB for users.

Comment: Under no normal circumstances should you duplicate a table.

Comment: What do you mean "switch db"?  Just establish 2 connections...

Comment: Isnt it better to have one? Im getting the info from the "users" connection at the begining, and after that i close it and one a "regular" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This greatly depends on the database you choose to use.**

If these "sub-projects" are designed to work as one coherent unit, then I strongly recommend you keep it all in the same database.   One backup, one restore, one unit.

For organizational purposes, if you are using a database which supports it, select a different Schema per project.  PostgreSQL and SQL Server are two databases (among others) which support this effortlessly.

In the case of a database like MySQL, I recommend you pick a short prefix for each subproject and prefix all tables accordingly.  "P1_Customer" for example.

Shared data would go in it's own schema or prefix, like Global or something like that.

Actually, this was one of the many reasons we switched our main database from MySQL to PostgreSQL.  We've been heavy users of both, and I really appreciate the features that PostgreSQL offers.  SQL Server, if you are in a windows environment, is a great database IMO as well.

Comment: Great answer. We are using MySQL and i will got one big DB. Thanks @gahooa

Answer (score 1):

If the little projects are "features of the big one" then I don't see a reason why you wouldn't want just one `user` table for the main project. The way you setup the question makes this seem true "If there is a user A in little project 1, then there must be a user A in the 'big' project." If that is true, you should likely have the users in the big db instead of doing duplication unless you have more qualifying details.

Comment: You understood correctly, and after reading all the posts i think that i will go for one big DB. Thanks @skaz

Answer (score 1):

i think the proper answer is 'it depends'.

Starting your organization down the path of  single centralized system is good on many levels.  I think in general i would recommend this.

however:

if you are going to have dramatically different development schedules, or dramatically different user experiences with the various sub projects, then you may be better off keeping them separate.

Comment: Thanks @Randy, i think that i try to centralize it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at OpenID or some other single sign-on protocol depending on the nature of your application. OpenID includes a mechanism called "attribute exchange", which allows applications to retrieve profile information from the OpenID provider.

This allows you to create a central user profile repository, with an authentication scheme, and have your individual apps query that repository for profile information.

The question as to how to design your database is hard to answer without more information. In most architectures, "features" within an application tend to be closely linked - "users" are related to "accounts" are related to "organisations" etc.

I'd recommend looking at the foreign key relationships to answer this question. If you have lots of foreign keys, build a single database for all tables. If you have "clusters" of foreign keys, and you want to have a different life cycle for each application (assuming the clusters map neatly to the applications), consider separate databases.

By "life cycle", I mean mostly the development lifecycle - app 1 might deploy weekly, app 2 monthly, app 3 once only and then be frozen.